# connection refused when I want to telnet my Ubuntu ip

Tags: ubuntu, virtual, valgrind, telnet, printers

fiji/rel_x10.11/output/desktop/etc/init.d$ telnet 192.168.223.129 9100
Trying 192.168.223.129...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused,
It looks like that my Ubuntu ip refused the connection ,but I do not get why,how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible reasons, but four come immediately to mind.

1. The IP address is invalid.
2. The IP address is unreachable because of an error in routing table configuration on intermediate nodes.
3. A firewall somewhere is refusing to admit the traffic.
4. The target host has inetd so configured as not to accept inbound telnet requests.